# MPI and OpenMP. Do I even have a choice?

Tags: mpi, openmp, linear-algebra, lapack, intel-fortran

I have a linear algebra code that I am trying get to run faster. Its a iterative algorithm with a loop and matrix vector multiplications within in.
So far, I have used MATMUL (Fortran Lib.), DGEMV, Tried writing my own MV code in OpenMP but the algorithm is doing no better in terms of scalability. Speed ups are barely 3.5 - 4 irrespective of how many processors I am allotting to it (I have tried up 64 processors).
The profiling shows significant time being spent in Matrix-Vector and the rest is fairly nominal.
My question is: 
I have a shared memory system with tons of RAM and processors. I have tried tweaking OpenMP implementation of the code (including Matrix Vector) but has not helped. Will it help to code in MPI? I am not a pro at MPI but the ability to fine tune the message communication might help a bit but I can't be sure. Any comments?

More generally, from the literature I have read, MPI = Distributed, OpenMP = Shared but can they perform well in the others' territory? Like MPI in Shared? Will it work? Will it be better than the OpenMP implementation if done well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MPI in a shared environment (though not OpenMP in a distributed one). However, achieving a good speedup depends a lot more on your algorithms and data dependencies than the technology used. Since you have a lot of shared memory, I'd recommend you stick with OpenMP, and carefully examine whether you're making the best use of your resources.

Answer (score 4):

You're best off just using a linear algebra package that is already well optimized for a multitcore environment and using that for your matrix-vector multiplication.   The [Atlas](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) package, [gotoblas](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2) (if you have a nehalem or older; sadly it's no longer being updated), or vendor BLAS implementations (like [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/) for intel CPUs, [ACML](http://developer.amd.com/libraries/acml/pages/default.aspx) for AMD, or [VecLib](http://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/ve/vector_libraries.html) for apple, which all cost money) all have good, well-tuned, multithreaded BLAS implementations.  Unless you have excellent reason to believe that you can do better than those full time development teams can, you're best off using them.

Note that you'll never get the parallel speedup with DGEMV that you do with DGEMM, just because the vector is smaller than another matrix and so there's less work; but you can still do quite well, and you'll find you get much better perforamance with these libraries than you do with anything hand-rolled unless you were already doing multi-level cache blocking.

Comment: Are you using the multithreaded MKL (with Composer XE, adding -mkl=parallel ?) What is your speedup with multhreaded vs single threaded, and why are you concerned that it's not enough?  You shouldn't have to rewrite any of _your_ code to use the multithreaded libraries.

Comment: My compile flags are:
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=4

ifort -fp-model source Code.f90 -L$MKLROOT/lib/ia32 -lmkl_blas95 -lmkl_intel -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -openmp -lpthread && time ./a.out 
I use VTune for profiling